# How do i reorder lists in python to correspond with a pre-defined order

Tags: list

I want to create a bespoke shopping list application using python. I want the application to give me a list that is in order of the items as i walk around my shop.

How do i write python code that re-orders a list so that the items appear in a specifically pre-defined order.

For instance, if i my shopping included: eggs, milk, bacon, bread, tomatoes. I want to write code so that whatever the i input in the list the output is always sorted so that when the list is printed bread is first, tomatoes is second etc.

Answer (score 0):

Robin, welcome to Stack Exchange.   Here's the approach (I'll leave the code to you):   Create a dictionary that maps items into their order in the store.  Then, given a shopping list, sort it based on the dictionary values for the items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you know what will be in your list at all times (whether there will always be the same items).

If you did know, you could use a dictionary to link each known item to its index in a list. For example:

```
shoppingorder = {"bread":0, "tomatoes":1}    #The number is the index for the item
   
shoppinglist = []
shoppinglist.insert(shoppingorder["bread"], "bread")
```

You could also combine this with an input:

```
item = input("Please enter a shopping item")
for x in range(len(shoppingorder)):
    shoppinglist.append("") #To avoid index errors

if item in shoppingorder:
    shoppinglist.insert(shoppingorder[item], item)
else:
    print(item + " is not in the list of valid items!")
```

If you do not know the items or their orders, you will have to get the user to specify the index for the item on input, and store this in the dictionary:

```
shoppingorder = {}
shoppinglist = []

item = input("Enter the item")
order= int(input("Enter the position in the list"))

shoppingorder[item] = order
```

The code above is very basic, and you will need to add error handling, duplicate handling and proper inputting tools as required yourself.